# converting the image into Base64 code (Status code is 500)

Tags: ios, swift, api, base64

I facing some error when i want to send some data on the server. And this the problem is when i converting the image into Base64 code, then it will create some problem. Please help me to resolve this issue. The data could not be in correct format and status code is 500. I don't know how to  resolve this.

Error:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1c043c2c0> { URL: http://192.168.1.58/api/visitor/store } { Status Code: 500, Headers {

    "Cache-Control" =     (

        "no-cache, private"
    );
    Connection =     (
        close
    );

    "Content-Type" =     (

        "text/html; charset=UTF-8"

    );

    Date =     (
        "Mon, 19 Mar 2018 05:11:06 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (

        "Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.1"

    );

    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (

        Identity

    );

    Vary =     (

        Authorization

    );

    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        "PHP/7.1.1"
    );

    "X-RateLimit-Limit" =     (

        60

    );
    "X-RateLimit-Remaining" =     (
        59
    );
} }

The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

My Code is :

```
func apiToSaveData(strURL: String)

    {

        let myURL = URL(string: strURL)



        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myURL!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")



        let token = "Bearer " + strToken

        request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")



        var postString: [String : String] = ["" : ""]

        if let navController = self.navigationController, navController.viewControllers.count >= 2

        {

            //Comes from After VerifyOTP after Returning Screen

            let viewController = navController.viewControllers[navController.viewControllers.count - 2]

            if viewController.restorationIdentifier == "VerifyOTP"

            {

                postString = ["image": strEncodedImg, "name": tfName.text!, "phone": tfMobile.text!, "email": tfEmail.text!, "otp": strOTP]

            }



            else if viewController.restorationIdentifier == "VisitorVC"

            {

                let imgObj = otlBtnTakeImage.imageView?.image

                let imgData: Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgObj!)!

                let strEncodedImg1 = imgData.base64EncodedString()

                print("ENcodedImage: \(strEncodedImg1)")

               postString = ["image": strEncodedImg1, "name": tfName.text!, "phone": tfMobile.text!, "email": tfEmail.text!]
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Nobody even knows how you are converting an image object to a base64 string object.

Comment: Do you how to convert the image into base64 and pass to the server

Comment: 500 errors likely means the problem is on the server side, you should've get 4XX errors if the request was malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first convert your data which is in the form of dictionary into json and send it to server
So, add this code into your api function.

```
func apiToSaveData(strURL: String)
    {
        let myURL = URL(string: strURL)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myURL!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let token = "Bearer " + strToken

        request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        var postString: [String : String] = ["" : ""]

        if let navController = self.navigationController, navController.viewControllers.count >= 2
        {
            //Comes from After VerifyOTP after Returning Screen
            let viewController = navController.viewControllers[navController.viewControllers.count - 2]

            if viewController.restorationIdentifier == "VerifyOTP"
            {
                postString = ["image": strEncodedImg, "name": tfName.text!, "phone": tfMobile.text!, "email": tfEmail.text!, "otp": strOTP]

            }

            else if viewController.restorationIdentifier == "VisitorVC"
            {
                let imgObj = otlBtnTakeImage.imageView?.image
                let imgData: Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgObj!)!
                let strEncodedImg1 = imgData.base64EncodedString()
                print("ENcodedImage: \(strEncodedImg1)")

               postString = ["image": strEncodedImg1, "name": tfName.text!, "phone": tfMobile.text!, "email": tfEmail.text!]
            }
        }

        do {
            // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options: .prettyPrinted)

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        let postTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        print(response!)

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            //create json object from data
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                print("POST Method :\(json)")


                if dict["status"] as? String == "1"
                {

            }

        } catch let error {

            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    postTask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you a complete solution and try it.

Step 1: Declare global variable.

```
var imageDataForApi:Data!
```

Step 2: Put this code in imagePickerController `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

```
 if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        imageview.image = image
        let sonu = getFileName(info: info)
        print(sonu)
        if sonu == "JPG"
        {
            imageDataForApi = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        }
        else if sonu == "PNG"
        {
            imageDataForApi = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0)
        }
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true) { () -> Void in

    }
```

Step 3: Paste this function blow viewdidload.

```
func getFileName(info: [String : Any]) -> String {

    if let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
        let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetPath], options: nil)
        let asset = result.firstObject
        let fileName = asset?.value(forKey: "filename")
        let fileUrl = URL(string: fileName as! String)
        if let name = fileUrl?.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent {
            print(name)


            let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
            if (assetPath.absoluteString.hasSuffix("JPG")) {
                sonu = "JPG"
                print("JPG")
            }
            else if (assetPath.absoluteString.hasSuffix("PNG")) {
                sonu = "PNG"
                print("PNG")
            }
            else if (assetPath.absoluteString.hasSuffix("GIF")) {
                sonu = "GIF"
                print("GIF")
            }
            else {
                sonu = "Unknown"
                print("Unknown")
            }

            return name
        }
    }
    return ""

}
```

Step 4: Call this method where you want.

```
 let strBase64 = imageDataForApi?.base64EncodedString()
    print(strBase64!)
```